# Abnormal heating up in Windows Phone 8.1 Preview

Tags: 8.1, battery

I am using Windows Phone 8.1 Preview since it was released. From day before yesterday my phone is getting hotter (really very hot) and battery draining too faster. Same happened twice yesterday. I got a minor update yesterday afternoon. But heating up happened even after it. (Battery drainage related to location service is not yet fixed).

Comment: Which build are you on?

Comment: It's 8.10.12393.890 now.

Comment: Are you still experiencing the heat issues?

Comment: I submitted the phone to Nokia Care. I'll let you know more about the issue once I got my phone back. (Most probably, the hardware issue.)

Comment: It was a hardware issue and got a replacement :)

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your own question, and flag it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was with the hardware. I contacted Nokia Care and after one month I got replaced handset. This issue is not related with Windows 8.1 OS.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue, though the last update solved it for me.

You can always try a hard reset:
[Reset my phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/reset-my-phone)

Comment: I downgraded the OS to 8.0, problem was still there. I suspect that the issue with hardware, antenna may be.